# Creating 3d Tensor Array from 2d Array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays (4x4 each). I would like to concatenate them to a tensor of (4x4x2) in which the first 'sheet' is the first array, second 'sheet' is the second array, etc. However, when I try `np.stack` the output of `d[1]` is not showing the correct values of the first matrix.

```
import numpy as np
x = array([[ 3.38286851e-02, -6.11905173e-05, -9.08147798e-03,
        -2.46860166e-02],
       [-6.11905173e-05,  1.74237508e-03, -4.52140165e-04,
        -1.22904439e-03],
       [-9.08147798e-03, -4.52140165e-04,  1.91939979e-01,
        -1.82406361e-01],
       [-2.46860166e-02, -1.22904439e-03, -1.82406361e-01,
         2.08321422e-01]])
print(np.shape(x)) # 4 x 4

y = array([[ 6.76573701e-02, -1.22381035e-04, -1.81629560e-02,
        -4.93720331e-02],
       [-1.22381035e-04,  3.48475015e-03, -9.04280330e-04,
        -2.45808879e-03],
       [-1.81629560e-02, -9.04280330e-04,  3.83879959e-01,
        -3.64812722e-01],
       [-4.93720331e-02, -2.45808879e-03, -3.64812722e-01,
         4.16642844e-01]])
print(np.shape(y)) # 4 x 4

d = np.dstack((x,y))
np.shape(d) # indeed it is 4,4,2... but if I do d[1] then it is not the first x matrix.
d[1] # should be y
```

Comment: You expect `d[1]` to be `y`, no? `d[0]` -> `x`?

Comment: you are right! making correction to comment now. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `np.dstack((x, y))`, which is the same as the more explicit `np.stack((x, y), axis=-1)`, you are concatenating along the last, not the first axis (i.e., the one with size 2):

```
(x == d[..., 0]).all()
(y == d[..., 1]).all()
```

Ellipsis (`...`) is a python object that means "`:` as many times as necessary" when used in an index. For a 3D array, you can equivalently access the leaves as

```
d[:, :, 0]
d[:, :, 1]
```

If you want to access the leaves along the first axis, your array must be `(2, 4, 4)`:

```
d = np.stack((x, y), axis=0)
(x == d[0]).all()
(y == d[1]).all()
```

Comment: Awesome answer! What if I don't have an initial array and want to stack iteratively?

Comment: @sarah. That's a frequent question. Either estimate how much you'll need and pre-allocate, or append to a list until you're done. Reallocating the entire buffer over and over is going to be a major bottleneck.

Comment: That is true, how would we allocate a 4x4 initial array and then stack the subsequent on top?

Comment: @sarah. I *highly* recommend you don't do that. But you can do `np.zeros((0, 4, 4))` or `(4, 4, 0)`. But again, use a list or pre-allocate the maximum size instead.

Comment: quick question- once I stack the matrices, how do I delete a matrix? For example I want to delete the first one d[0]?

Comment: @sarah. The first by slicing: `d = d[1:]`. Interior ones, by `np.delete`. Again, use a list until the size stops changing. Deleting a 4-byte reference from a list is much cheaper than moving a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.stack` instead of `np.dstack`:

```
>>> d = np.stack([y, x])

>>> np.all(d[0] == y)
True

>>> np.all(d[1] == x)
True

>>> d.shape
(2, 4, 4)
```